# ArgumentNullException for ConnectionString When trying to remotely connect to .net core API

Tags: c#, .net-core

First of all is this happening in a Mac and I'm new to dotnet core.

I have installed dockers and setup everything in dotnet core. I did add connectionstring to the 'appsettings' and 'appsettings(Development)'.

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "Default": "server=localhost; database=Monitor; User ID=sa; Password=MyComplexpPassword!234;"
  },
```

This is Program.cs file Main method

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
      CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
 }
```

This is startup.cs class ConfigureServices method.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
      services.AddAutoMapper();

      services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

      services.AddDbContext<MonitorDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
      services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
      {
           configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
      });

      services.AddScoped<IUserRepository,UserRepository>();
 }
```

This is a Controller test method to test API.

```
[HttpGet("getUser")]
public UserResource GetUserInfo()
{
       var user_1 = new User();

       user_1.FirstName = "MAC";
       user_1.LastName = "OS TEST";
       user_1.Username = "Apple@gmail.com";


       return mapper.Map<User, UserResource>(user_1);
}
```

This method will perfectly execute If I make a rest call(http) without setting up Program.cs class for remote access.

[image]

Now I have set it up to run in 'http://0.0.0.0:6001', So that I can access the API from my phone or from another pc in the same wifi.
I followed [This instructions](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/28/External-Network-Access-to-Kestrel-and-IIS-Express-in-ASPNET-Core).

Now My Program.cs main method is like this.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
       // CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

       var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddCommandLine(args)
                .Build();


       var hostUrl = configuration["hosturl"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hostUrl))
                hostUrl = "http://0.0.0.0:6000";


       var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel()
                .UseUrls(hostUrl)   // <!-- this 
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseIISIntegration()
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseConfiguration(configuration)
                .Build();

            host.Run();

}
```

In terminal I ran this command `dotnet run --hosturl http://0.0.0.0:6001`

If try to access same method as before this happens.
[image]

Notice:- I changed only the host, Because I need to test the API with other devices.

I have other controllers and methods that are connecting to the database and do crud operations with it, Those API calls also face the same issue like this. This only happens if I set it up to remote access.

Notice:- If I change the Startup.cs class Connection string line like this, It will work flawlessly in both configurations.

```
services.AddDbContext<MonitorDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer("server=localhost; database=Monitor; User ID=sa; Password=MyComplexpPassword!234;"));
```

But I felt that this is not good practice. In future, I have to add JWT Authentication to the API so that APP_Secret also needed to add to the AppSettings.json file.

Thank you.

Comment: If the only place you add config from is the command line, yet your config is stored in the command line, how did you expect this to work? Have you looked at the documentation to see how to add configuration from a file?

Comment: @mason Would you can explain, What should I configure?

Comment: Do you see where you set up your configuration? It says AddCommandLine, right? But you aren't passing a connection string on the command line, are you? You have it in the configuration file, yet you haven't told it to read configuration from the config file. The documentation explains how it works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#file-configuration-provider

Comment: @mason I think configuration in Startup and configuration in Program is not the same configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you didn't tell the application to use `appsettings.json`. change below configuration

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();
```

To

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .Build();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It needs some changes and it was the solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can use the static [`WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webhost.createdefaultbuilder?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method which by default loads settings from 'appsettings.json', 'appsettings.[EnvironmentName].json', *and* command line args.

Note -> As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#command-line-configuration-provider):

> `AddCommandLine` has already been called by `CreateDefaultBuilder`. If you
>   need to provide app configuration and still be able to override that
>   configuration with command-line arguments, call the app's additional
>   providers in `ConfigureAppConfiguration` and call `AddCommandLine` last.

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
    {
        // Call other providers here and call AddCommandLine last.
        config.AddCommandLine(args);
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
```